# aiogram перестает отправлять сообщения

Tags: python, многопоточность, aiogram, бот

Всем привет.
Изучаю Python и для практики делаю бот парсер.
Так вот, у меня есть бесконечный цикл, который рассылает картинку с описанием из бд конкретным пользователям.
Проблема в том что работа этой функции в какой-то момент останавливается, через try exept ошибок не получаю. Такое чувство что она просто повисает либо в ожидании, либо поток завершается, но отловить и узнать это я не могу.
При этом есть идентичная функция, которая работает в другом потоке и она работает исправно.
Может поможете с тем как отловить проблему и узнать причину.

```
def show(): 
   global loop
   while True:
      time.sleep(1.0)
      try:        
            try:
                     temp = q.get() 
                     car=  temp['car']
                     user_id=temp['user'][0]
                     cs= db.check_search(user_id=user_id) 
                     if cs==True: 
                        db.on_show_db(user_id,car[0])
                        link = hlink('\nОткрыть',car[0])
                        desc = car[1]
                        desc = desc+link
                        img_link = car[2]
                        img = func.get_id_car(img_link)
                        func.save_car_img(img_link,img)
                        img = func.get_image_link(img)
                        
                        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(bot.send_photo(user_id, photo=InputFile(img), caption=desc,reply_markup=inline_kb1),loop)
                          
            except Exception as e:
                     print(e)

      except Exception as e:
       print(e)
```

Comment: `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` в бесконечном цикле? К тому же в синхронном. Сделайте функцию асинхронной, а `bot.send_photo(…)` в `await`.

Comment: Сделал так потому что данная функция выполняется в отдельном потоке( чтобы бот не зависал в ожидании ответа). использовал ```asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe``` чтобы возвращать отправку фото в поток где работает бот, иначе не получилось.